# Javahelp viewers (or alternatives)

Tags: java, javahelp

I'm trying to integrate searchable help into my Java (Swing) application. I'm using docbook right now to generate pdf help, and I know it can generate JavaHelp. I think the default viewer for JavaHelp is rather unappealing though (especially on windows, even when using the windows L&F). I couldn't find any nice looking viewers, but curious if you know of any out there, or if there are better alternatives for help within the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default content viewer (HTML renderer) in [JavaHelp](http://javahelp.java.net/) is [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html). This component is not very impressive; it only supports HTML 3.2 and has limited CSS capabilities. It is possible to plug in [alternative content viewers in JavaHelp](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/brinkley/archive/2004/11/javahelp_v20_02.html).

You might want to try [Oracle Help](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index-083946.html). It is very similar to JavaHelp, but more actively maintained. The default content viewer that comes with Oracle Help is also more capable. The DocBook-XSL JavaHelp stylesheets may require some tweaking in order to produce output that works with Oracle Help (see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/doc.1112/e16280/appendix_a.htm)).

It is hard to find definitive information about status and future plans for these technologies. JavaHelp had its latest release in October 2007, while Oracle Help 11.1.2.1.0 was released in September 2011. There are forums ([here](https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java_desktop/javahelp_system/content) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/oracle_help_technologies/content)), but the activity is low.

Perhaps you'd be interested in a web/browser-based help system. In that case take a look at [WebHelp](http://snapshots.docbook.org/xsl-ns/webhelp/docs/), one of the newer output formats for DocBook content.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for all my documentation needs and it has excellent HTML templates. The sphinx site itself is based on one of the templates. There is also [eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rest-editor) that helps you setup the base sphinx project and acts as the editor. Advantages

1. You write the documentation using ReST syntax which is similar to wiki.
2. Good looking html templates/
3. Ability to generate other formats like epub, pdf etc.
4. Versionable

Comment: Have you been able to use this documentation from within a help viewer in your app? Or is it only in external files.

Comment: @JeffStorey It is ny external files

Comment: We currently use docbook to pdf/html for that which works well. I'm trying to find an alternative (or at least a better viewer) for JavaHelp.